# How to hide keyboard by default and show only when click on EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have multiple Edittext in my activity i want to hide by defult keyboard when view shows and show keyboard only when edittext is clicked 
i am not getting how to do this
thanks Advance:)

Comment: there are lots of answer, non of  them working ?

Comment: Here is also a hack for you, only added a linearlayout into your xml file. https://gist.github.com/XinyueZ/cc0be271686491dcf6e6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this.

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();

    answer_et.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(
        Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(edit_text.getWindowToken(), 0);
        }
    }, 100);

}
```

sometime edittext get focus after manually hide soft-keyboard.

so, delay 100 mSeconds and then after hide it forcefully in onResume() method.

Comment: Or just add a view in the top layout, as the first view, as such:     <View
        android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="0dp" android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"/>